# open ssh tunnel in R script

Tags: r, postgresql, ssh, rpostgresql

I connect to a PostgreSQL DB via RPostgres to perform queries.

My current workflow is the following:

1. In the terminal, I create a tunnel via ssh.

   ```
   ssh -L PORT:host:25060
   ```
2. On top of my R script, I create the DB connection:

   ```
   # use RPostgres library
   require(RPostgres)

   # create db instance 
   db = dbConnect(
      Postgres(), 
      user = 'user',
      password = 'password',
      dbname = 'dbname',
      host = '127.0.0.1',
      port = 5433,
      sslmode = 'require'
      )
   ```
3. I then query the database.

Every time I relaunch the R session or connect to a different tunnel, or I want to schedule a script, this procedure doesn't work.

Is there a way to incorporate the tunnel creation in thee R script? Moreover, how to properly encrypt the password and sensitive information?

Best,

Comment: Did you try to creat the tunnel using `system` command? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html For the password, it will always be stored in clear "somewhere", to you must ensure that this "somewhere" is not accessible from outside

Comment: I successfully created the tunnel via `system()`. When I run the command executing it normally in the script, it works and opens the tunnel. When I `source('')` the previous script on top of another R script I get an error like: `bind [127.0.0.1]:5433: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5433
Could not request local forwarding.` I still am able to create the connection tho.